# how to center links within <header>?

Tags: html, css

I have 4 links and 1 img within  in the the following order:

first link - second link - img - link third - fourth link

the img is centered, but the links do not line up like the img.

- using chrome
- looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ktw19.png

HTML

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <a href="#inicio">INICIO</a>
        <a href="#nosotros">NOSOTROS</a>
        <a href="#inicio"><img url ("http://i.imgur.com/5708znM.png") alt="Sookies"></a>
        <a href="#productos">PRODUCTOS</a>
        <a href="#contacto">CONTACTO</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
* { 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: #2c3e50;
    color: #fff;
}

header nav {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; they line up just fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/n4Px4/

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: do you mean vertically?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without your image, but use `vertical-align:top` on `a` and you can use `margin-top` to adjust from there

Comment: Using margin-top is unnecessary... vertical-align:middle should be used instead on the image.

Answer (score -1):

Your links are not centring horizontally because of:

```
header nav {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-right: 50px; <-- This
    padding-left: 50px; <-- This
}
```

It will first apply your padding to the right because it is presented before padding-left, so that is why it is moved to the right a little. Remove it!

To center your logo vertically, add this to your image:

```
img {
     vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ufPNY/

If this answers your question, please up-vote it and mark it as the answer.

Comment: guys, thank you very much, with your help I found the solution was not to center on link, was to center the image

img {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
I like how it turned out http://i.imgur.com/2H51Diw.png                    I was not the -1